# Android Bluetooth Delay

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing an app which requires that I play a song in two phones via Bluetooth. At the time I am able to do so, but with a delay in playing sounds.

The way I am doing this is by sending a string over bluetooth which when sent tells the app to play a song and when received do the same.

Of course there will be a delay because of the bluetooth connection but the main problem is that this delay is not constant at all so I am having trouble in synchronize both well..

Any suggestions will be really appreciated :)